# NuGet Packages and out parameters

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, communicationexception

I have a few classes with methods defined in a NuGet package. Some of these methods have "out parameters" and it seems that when I try to call these methods with out keyword an exception of type `System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException` is thrown.

Does anyone know why this exception is being thrown?

Are out parameters not allowed when calling Nuget packages?

I tried to bind each parameter manually using colons but I still see the same issue.

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException:  There was an error while
>   trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:personalCode.  The
>   InnerException message was 'Type 'Personal' with data contract name 
>   'Personal:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataContracts' is
>   not expected.  Add any types not known statically to the list of known
>   types - for example,   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by
>   adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.'.   Please see InnerException for more
>   details. --->  System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 
>   Type 'PersonalCode' with data contract name 
>   'PersonalCode:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataContracts'
>   is not expected.  Add any types not known statically to the list of
>   known types - for example,   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute
>   or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Please show how you are calling this function, and how the function itself is defined.

Comment: You need either ref or out in the parameter call so the value get send as a pointer instead of By value.  By Value will put values on the execution stack.

Comment: I think th e`out` parameters are a red herring, have you seen these two articles: https://forum.uipath.com/t/error-while-opening-the-packages-manager-window/1100/3 and less relevant https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f41fde9-b589-4457-9760-7de0ad87e5e4/wcf-type-applicationexception-with-data-contract-name-is-not-expected?forum=wcf